# Receiving an Java unreachable code

Tags: java

I am receiving an unreachable code error when typing up this code. I am not sure why, is it because I don't have an Else in this If statement?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pickNumbers {
    Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    float[] pickNumbers(int choice) {
        float[] myFloats = new float[2];
        do { // do loop will continue until user enters correct response
            System.out.print("Please enter 2 numbers separated by a space in the formats of floats: "); // will prompt user to enter 2 floats
            try {
                myFloats[0] = readInput.nextFloat(); // will read first float entered
                myFloats[1] = readInput.nextFloat(); // will read second float entered
                if (choice == 4 && myFloats[1] == 0.0f)
                    ;
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot complete calculation. Cannot divide by 0, please try again.");
                    myFloats[0] = myFloats[1] = 0.0f;
                    continue;
                }
                break; // i am receiving an error here saying unreachable code and i don't know why

            } catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input. Try again.");
                readInput.nextLine(); // discard input that is not a float
                continue; // loop will continue until the correct answer is found
            }
        } while (true);
        return myFloats; // an an unreachable error here also
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look in your if statement, it has a semicolon out of place, should be:

```
if (choice == 4 && myFloats[1] == 0.0f) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a semicolon after your `if (choice == 4 && myFloats[1] == 0.0f)` statement and anything after that is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

You have `;` just after the following `if` statement

```
if (choice == 4 && myFloats[1] == 0.0f)
```

Because of this, your `if` statement is completed and the following `continue` will make `break` as unreachable code.